# How may i implement smooth scroll functionality?

Tags: jquery, scrollbar

I can implement smooth scroll functionality on my website using this jQuery code:

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {

var target = $( $(this).attr('href') );

    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 1000);

});
```

then i put a pretty circular image which will redirect user to the part of website i want
simply with the following code:

```
<a href="#contact"> <img src="circular.png"> </a>
```

Everything is working well but i want to allow users to scroll my site with mousewheel,when scrollbar is disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer myself.

i should use HTML *onmousewheel* event.